# Django REST Login error. I don't know what to do

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

Well Im trying to login with an API call. I got a model called User. I want make the login from this Model using email and password. This is my Model:

```
class User(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
surnames = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=60)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
country = CountryField()
phonenumber = PhoneNumberField()
postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=5)

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

I have this API call login User:

```
class UserLogin(APIView):

permission_classes = []

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = authenticate(email=request.data.get('email'), password=request.data.get('password'))
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(request, user.email)
        return render(request, 'core/core_index.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Error')
```

With this backend to authenticate:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from apps.core.models import User as UserAPI

class MyBackEnd(object):
def authenticate(self, request, email, password):
    """
    :param username: Username of the user
    :param password: Password of the user
    :return:
    """
    #check is user is present in User DB.
    existing_user = None
    try:
        existing_user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        return existing_user
    except Exception as e:
        #Checking the user UserAPI Custom DB.
        user_data = UserAPI.objects.get(email=email)
        if email == user_data.email:
            user =  User.objects.create_user(username=user_data.name ,email=email,password=password)
            user.save()
            return User.objects.get(email=email)
        else:
            return None

def get_user(self, user_id):

    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

I have got the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['apps.core.api.backends.MyBackEnd']
setted on settings.py.

I tried a lot of things and all with errors, I don't know what to do, If anyone have a solution please.

Comment: Change `login(request, user.email)` to `login(request, user)`

Comment: Whats the error? Did you override ``AUTH_USER_MODEL``?

Comment: @n1rna I tried it, but this error appears -  AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Pedro After adding some required parameters, I get stuck on this - 'User' object has no attribute 'is_anonymous'

Comment: Couple of things. You are not using the password to authenticate, just looking the user by email. Besides, you are storing the password in plain text, this is bad bad bad. Third, why are you replacing the user model instead of extending it? I think that what you want is to have some kind of profile for your users, I recommend that you craft a model with the wanted fields that has a OneToOneField to User if this is the case. If you still want to customize the default User please refer to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user)